# Metric spaces exercise of $x^2\sin(1/x^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$$

$$\begin{align}x\to \begin{cases} x^2\sin(1/x^2)& \text{if}& x>0
\\0&\text{if}&x=0\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Show that the function $f$ has a unlimited derivative, with the help of metric spaces. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous? 
What am I supposed to do to prove the last statements? Thanks for reading!

Comment: **Formatting tip:** When entering trig functions, notice that adding \ before the functions looks much better 
see `$sin x$` gives $sin x$ whereas `$\sin x$` gives $\sin x$. The same goes in the case of log functions, see 
`$\log x$` and `$\ln x$` give $\log x$ and $\ln x$ and look better, as opposed to `$log x$` and `$ln x$` which 
give $log x$ and $ln x$.

Comment: When $n\in \mathbb N$ and $x=1/\sqrt {1/\pi n}\;$ we have $f'(x)=-2(-1)^n\sqrt {\pi n}$ so $f'$ is unbounded above or below.

Answer (score 2):

The function's clearly differentiable at any $\;x\neq0\;$ as a product of two differentiable functions, and at zero ( from the right, as the function's defined only at $\;[0,1]\;$):

$$f'(0):=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^2\sin\frac1{x^2}}x=\lim_{x\to0^+} x\sin\frac1{x^2}=0$$

as the last one is the limit of a function that vanishes at the limit times a *bounded* one... Thus, also at zero the function's differentiable from the right.

As $\;f\;$ is differentiable everywhere (and one-sided at the extreme points), it is continuous, and a continuous function on a closed bounded (i.e., compact) sert is uniformly continuous there